# Thoughts on users posting URLs and their partial content as their answer?

Tags: discussion

What are peoples thoughts on accepting/up voting answers where a user has simply copied a few lines from another website and used that as their answer?

I don't really like and would down vote those answers unless you

- Made it clear that the content is from another site
- You include a link the the URL you sourced your material from
- Actually put your own thoughts into the answer

I came across this question [Multi-Mode and Single-Mode Fiber Differences](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/493/multi-mode-and-single-mode-fiber-differences) which I have down voted because firstly the user just posted the first 3 lines from some random website and secondly the URL was incorrect and thirdly I don't think it's a very good quality answer.

Is this a fair assessment and should we discourage these kinds of answers? What if the website were to vanish over night?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, exactly.

Stack Exchange guidance is an answer should stand on its own. URLs shoiuld be included as a citation if the answer is not the poster's own work.

If you, or anyone, see spammy Qs or As, please flag them for moderator review.